# Dividir datos usando varios separadores

Tags: r

Tengo un csv con campos separados por "|"
Por ejemplo:

```
Antonio|López|Calle Azul nº23|20123|panadero|lunes
```

Quiero abrirlo y pasarlo a xlsx.
Pero hay un problema.
En una de las celdas aparece algo como esto:

```
Antonio|López|Calle Azul (nº23)|20123|panadero|lunes
```

y creo que el simbolo )| no lo procesa bien y entonces no divide los datos,
quedando todos los datos en 3 campos.

```
Antonio   -----  López --------Calle Azul (nº23)|20123|panadero|lunes
```

por lo que me descuadra todo el fichero.

He intentado separar los datos de esta manera:

```
fichero <- read.delim("fichero.csv", header=T, sep=c('|',')|'), fileEncoding="latin1")
```

pero no funciona.

[fichero zip con un csv](https://gofile.io/d/WfAtBj)

Haciendo

```
fichero <- read.delim("prueba.csv", header=T, sep=c('|'), fileEncoding="latin1")

for(i in 1:ncol(fichero)) {
  print(i)
  print(max(nchar(fichero[,i])))
}
```

La primera columna contiene un dato de 767 caracteres. La celda no se ha dividido bien.

Es el registro 79745

```
which(nchar(fichero[,1])==767)
```

Si lo paso a xlsx no sale bien

```
library(writexl)
write_xlsx(fichero, "prueba.xlsx")
```

Comment: Acabo de probarlo y la importación de la línea de ejemplo funciona perfecto, incluso usando solo el `|` como delimitador. Tal vez tengas algún problema con la codificación , tal vez es unicode y tienes caracteres similares al pipe, pero distintos: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10572877/6836377. De cualquier manera sin poder analizar el archivo va a ser difícil ayudarte.

Comment: Añado un csv que no es el original pero tiene el mismo problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has encontrado un buen dato, las filas que tienen algún tipo de error producen que la fila completa sea leída en la primer columna. Podemos usar esto com patrón para analizar:

```
tail(sort(nchar(fichero[, 1])), 50)

 [1]  14  14  14  14  14  14  14  14  14  14  14  14  14  14  14  14  14  14  14  14  14  14  14  14
[25]  14  14  14  14  15  15  16 544 557 560 567 572 577 617 639 640 659 667 669 670 673 682 702 703
[49] 714 767
```

Interesante, tenemos una primer columna que como máximo llegaría a 16 caracteres y luego se "salta" a 544, de hecho hay varias líneas, podemos saber cuales son:

```
which(nchar(fichero[, 1]) >= 544)
 [1]  20343  24776  26420  29494  46455  60588  79745  84492 108894
[10] 112885 115052 120203 134053 134842 151866 155915 157419 160472
[19] 183613
```

Con un editor de texto, podemos revisar el archivo en esas lineas, por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sorpresa, tenemos unas comillas al principio de la siguiente fila

Ahi recordé que la función `read.delim()` tiene configurado por defecto este caracter, por lo que si lo deshabilitamos a la hora de importar el archivo:

```
fichero <- read.delim("Descargas/prueba.csv", header=TRUE, 
                      quote = "", sep=c('|'), 
                      fileEncoding="Latin1")

which(nchar(fichero[, 1]) >= 544)
integer(0)
```

Y ya no tenemos el problema inicial. Pero atención, esas filas igual han sido mal exportadas y habría que revisarlas.